# Django: Updating user information failed

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to write a form, through which the user can edit his own user information if he's already logged into the system.

here are the codes:

**forms.py:**

```
class UpdateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

**views.py:**

```
@login_required
def update_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        update_user_from = UpdateUserForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if update_user_from.is_valid():
            update_user_from.save()
        else:
            print(update_user_from.errors)
    else:
        update_user_from = UpdateUserForm()
        print("elseelse!")

    return render(request,
            'userprofile/update_user.html',
            {'update_user_from': update_user_from}
            )
```

**update_user.html:**

```
       ...
            <h1> Updating User informations of {{ user.username }}</h1>
            <form id="update_user_from" method="POST" action="/userprofile/update_user/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ update_user_form.as_p }}
                <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="Update"/>
            </form>
```

Those codes do not work properly: it always shows an "update" button directly after "Updating User informations of ...(a user name)", and the `print("elseelse!")` which I put in the `views.py` is always invoked, that means the condition `if request.method == "POST"` in `views.py` is not satisfied. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the mistype.  You mix the `update_user_from` in the python code with the `update_user_form` variable in the template. Note the `_from` and `_form` parts.

Also note that in the `GET` branch if the `if` statement you should pass the `instance` argument to the form constructor:

```
update_user_form = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
```